# How to find position (index) of elements based on a reference vector?

Tags: r, vector, indexing, position

Let's say I have a vector `V` of categorical variable `L = c("a", "b", "c")`:

```
V <- c("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "c")
```

I want to encode every value of `L` with numbers and update V according to this encoding.

So, the new vector is:

```
Vnew = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3)
```

Would you help me with it?

Comment: Try `match` ie. `match(V, unique(V))`

Comment: @AnandaMahto I was only looking at `V`. It could be done with `match(V, L)`

Comment: I'd have though of match, too: `match(V, L)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using `factor` and extract the underlying numeric representation. Usage would simply be:

```
as.numeric(factor(V, L))
# [1] 1 1 2 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `match`

```
match(V,L)
#[1] 1 1 2 3 2 3
```